# How do I draw a polyline with angularjs?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, model-view-controller

As title, I save a lot of coordinates in database, and I will get it when I click a button. I can display all markers when I click the button, but I can't draw a polyline with these markers.

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-app="AAA" ng-controller="Controller">       
<button ng-click="SendGetPath()">Get</button>    
<div class="maps">
    <!-- Add directive code (gmap directive) for show map and markers-->
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
        <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id">

            <ui-gmap-window options="windowOptions" show="windowOptions.show">
                <div style="max-width:200px">
                    <div class="header"><strong>{{marker.time}}</strong></div>
                </div>
            </ui-gmap-window>

        </ui-gmap-marker>

        <ui-gmap-polyline path="map.polyline.path" stroke="map.polyline.stroke" visible='map.polyline.visible' geodesic='map.polyline.geodesic' fit="false"></ui-gmap-polyline>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>

    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

And in javascript,

```
var app = angular.module('AAA', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, $http) {

//this is for default map focus when load first time
$scope.map = { center: { latitude: 22.25, longitude: 114.1667 }, zoom: 14, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }

$scope.carlist = [];    
$scope.locations = [];
var id = 1;      

//Send command to device
$scope.SendGetPath = function () {
    $http.get('GetPath', {
        params: {
            regno: document.getElementById('car').value,
            date: document.getElementById('date').value
        }
    }).then(function (data) {
        //alert("Sent"); 
        $scope.locations = data.data;
        $scope.markers = [];            
        angular.forEach($scope.locations, function (value, key) {
            $scope.markers.push({
                id: id,
                coords: { latitude: value.Latitude, longitude: value.Longitude },
                //title: value.RegNo,
                //battery: value.Battery
                //address: data.data.Address,
                //image : data.data.ImagePath                  
                time: value.Time
            });
            id=id+1;                
        });            

        $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 22.25, longitude: 114.1667 }, zoom: 12 }

    }, function () {
        //alert('Load Error');
    });
}          

});
```

And how do I add arrow to the path of the map?